# Bamboo won't trigger child plan if it is already running

Tags: parent-child, bamboo, circular-dependency

I have a pair of plans setup in Bamboo 5.8, let's call them plan A (smoke test) and plan B (full build and deploy).  Plan A is the parent and is set to trigger the child, plan B, with no other advanced or blocking strategies setup on the Dependencies tab. Plan B is only triggered as a child of plan A, no other triggers are enabled.  The problem I am seeing is that if plan B is already running and then a second plan A is triggered and finishes before the first plan B completes, when plan B finally finishes, it doesn't get triggered to run by the second plan A , it just sits there until a third plan A happens to be kicked off.
I'm not seeing any way to 'retry' a dependency trigger if the child plan is busy/currently building, is there something server side that needs to be changed or refreshed?  We only have 3 build agents.

Comment: Did you try the option of concurrent builds? I have no clue if that will fix it. But a build will not be triggered if the same project is already building.

Comment: @Prikkeldraad Unfortunately I can't use concurrent builds because they share a single slave resource.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also experiencing this issue. There is an eight year old, still open Atlassian support ticket for this: [BAM-2820](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-2820). Their workaround in there is to run concurrent builds, which doesn't work in my case because our builds use a shared resource.